# Bypass AJAX request, but keep script going inside success statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to bypass an AJAX request from running, but still keep the script going inside the success statement? I have a condition that is either true or false. If it's false, the AJAX request should be bypassed. But I still want the script to continue within the nested success function. For this reason, I'm unable to use this code...

```
beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
    if(bypass_ajax == 1) {
        xhr.abort();
    }
},
```

### Here's the code I'm trying to run...

```
   var bypass_ajax = true;

    $.ajax( {

        url: destination_url,
        data: { a:a, b:b },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( e ) {

            if( bypass_ajax == true ) {

                alert( 'Ajax request was manually bypassed, yet you can still read me...' );

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: So make it a method and put an if statement to say if X make Ajax call else call method...

Comment: @epascarello Then I have to write everything inside the success function twice (once inside the success function and once in the else statement). There's a a lot of nested code as well as a few AJAX calls. Writing if else statements would break the nesting and cause me to duplicate the code.

Comment: No you just create a named function. Then your success would call Foo(); And you wrap the ajax call in if(!bypass_ajax). And add a else statement that would call Foo();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you abort the request then it isn't going to be successful.

Refactor your code so you have a reusable function instead.

```
function success() {
    // success function
}

if (bypass_ajax) {
    success();
} else {
    $.ajax(...).done(success);
}
```